# Remove file in 'changes not staged for commit`

Tags: git

This is my git status:

```
# On branch create-views-question
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    solr/data/development/index/_0.fdt
#   deleted:    solr/data/development/index/_0.fdx
#   deleted:    solr/data/development/index/_0.fnm
#   deleted:    solr/data/development/index/_0.frq
...
```

Currently, i used `git rm` to remove one by one file, is there another way so i can remove them same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you could do

```
git rm 'solr/data/development/index/_0.*'
```

Note the `'` marks to prevent shell expansion and instead pass the `*` directly to git.

Here's an example:

```
graphite> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   deleted:    a
#   deleted:    b
#
no changes added to commit
graphite> git rm '*'
rm 'a'
rm 'b'
graphite> git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   deleted:    a
#   deleted:    b
#
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
git rm --cached `git status | grep deleted | sed 's#^.*:##'`
```

This removed all files listed with `deleted:` prefix in `git status`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I just want my local to look like remote, I like to do:

```
git reset --hard upstream/BRANCHNAME
```